# Implicit Function Theorem for Second Derivatives

Tags: matrix-calculus

Let $F:R^n \times R^m \to R^m$ be a function.
Suppose we have $F(x,y)=0$ where $y \in R^m$ is implicitly defined as a function of $x \in R^n$: $y=h(x)$. We have $F(x,h(x))=0$. 
By the Chain Rule, the Implicit Function Theorem can be derived: \begin{align*}
&D_xF + D_yF Dh = 0 \\
& \implies Dh = -(D_yF)^{-1} D_xF 
\end{align*}By taking the derivative again, we obtain 
\begin{align*}
\big( D_{xx}F + D_{xy}F Dh \big) + \big( D_{yx}F + D_{yy}F Dh \big) Dh + D_yF D^2h= 0
\end{align*}
I want to solve for $D^2h$. In this case, what is the meaning of the 'inverse' of $D_yF$?

If $F: R \to R$, the solution is simple and explained here:
[Implicit Function Theorem second derivative calculation help](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037753/implicit-function-theorem-second-derivative-calculation-help)

However, in my problem at hand, $h$ is necessarily a vector-valued function that takes a vector-argument. Does any one know a convenient way to express $D^2h$ (e.g. in a matrix or tensor format)?